# ID count with no duplicates

Tags: t-sql, join, duplicates

I have two tables.

Table 1) TEXT

| ID | #sentText |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |

Table 2) RECEIVED MESSAGE

| ID | DateReceivedMessage |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-10-24 |
| 2 | 2023-11-12 |
| 3 | NULL |
| 5 | 2023-05-18 |

How to join the above two tables so not to alter the sum of #SentText. So the final table output should like this.

| ID | #SentText | DateReceivedMessage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 2023-10-24 |
| 2 | NULL | 2023-11-12 |
| 3 | 1 | NULL |
| 5 | 2 | 2023-05-18 |

I tried Inner join but for ID 2  sent text is repeating and the final count is coming to 9 instead of 6.

Comment: `NULL` the value if  the `ROW_NUMBER` isn't `1`?

Comment: *coming to 9 instead of 6* I don't see `6` in your desired result

Comment: I *think* because they get `3 + 3 + 1 + 2` rather than `3 + NULL + 1 + 2`, @Stu , which is `9` and `6` respectively.

Comment: @ThomA great. didn't realize.

Comment: @Thom A great. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` based on the `ID` to achieve this. It will retrieve all rows from the `TEXT table`, even if they do not have a match in the `RECEIVED MESSAGE` table. Here is a SQL query that you can use:

```
SELECT
    T.ID,
    T.#sentText,
    R.DateReceivedMessage
FROM
    TEXT T
LEFT JOIN
    RECEIVED_MESSAGE R ON T.ID = R.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like there is a join criteria that is based specifically on the ordering of the data in your tables. That row numbering needs to be materialized in order for you to use it in your JOIN. We can do that using `row_number()` window function:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT ID, #sentText, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM table1
), t2 AS (
    SELECT ID, DateReceivedMessage, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateReceivedMessage) AS rn
    FROM table2
)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.#sentText, t2.DateReceivedMessage
FROM t1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
       ON t1.ID = t2.ID
       AND t1.rn = t2.rn
```

This would likely work on your sample data, but you may find this close, but not quite right as there is no inherent ordering in your TEXT table if `ID` is duplicated across rows.